# @DeclareParents fail to introduce new method

Tags: java, spring, aop

everybody, I am a beginner in Spring and I am encountering some problems with **@DeclareParents**. I follow the instructions in *Spring In Action* but I fail to realize the introduction.

Here are my codes.
I first define Interface performance

```
public interface Performance {
    void perform();
}
```

and then implement the interface.

```
@Component
public class OnePerformance implements Performance {
    @Autowired
    public OnePerformance(){
    }

    public void perform() {
        System.out.println("The Band is performing....");
    }
```

}

I want to introduce method **void performEncore()** into **Performance**.
So I define the Interface,

```
public interface Encoreable {
    void performEncore();
}
```

implement it,

```
@Aspect
public class DefaultEncoreable implements Encoreable{
    public void performEncore() {
        System.out.println("performEncore");
    }
}
```

and introduce it,

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class EncoreableIntroduction {            
    @DeclareParents(value="Performance+",
        , defaultImpl=DefaultEncoreable.class)
     public static Encoreable encoreable;
}
```

I use autoconfiguration,

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan
public class ConcertConfig {
}
```

However, when testing, I fail to introduce method void performEncore().

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes= ConcertConfig.class)
public class OnePerformanceTest {
    @Autowired
    private Performance performance;

    @Test
    public void perform() throws Exception {
        performance.perform();
}}
```

[image: Junit4 Test Class]

And I also enabled AspectJ Support Plugins.
[image: My IntelliJ IDEA PLUGIN Settings]

I have read the book and several blogs carefully but I still can not find the cause. So what may be the cause of this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you testing? jUnits?

Comment: yes, I'm testing with JUnit4

Comment: Can we see the Test class?

Comment: Sure, thank  you very much . There is a screen  capture in the description about the test class . Im in the gym atm but I will post the test class later.

Comment: Did you enable support in Intellij? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/enabling-aspectj-support-plugins.html

Comment: I have edited the description to show the Junit4 Class and IDEA settings. And I think I have enabled support.

Comment: I doubt your `Performer` is in the default package, so I would say that for starters the `value` of `@DeclareParents` is wrong. Second you are auto wiring a `Performer` and not a `Encoreable`. As you are using proxies (and not weaving) the method will only be available at run time. So in your test you should test if the `Performer` is an instance of `Encorable` cast it and call the method. That or switch to use compile time weaving instead (which complicates your setup).

Comment: Thank you guys for your help, I finally figured out the problem. :-D I referred to the official document and M.Deinum's solution is to the point. My JUnit4 class is not correct. I cast **Performance** into **Encoreable**, and the encoreable call the **performEncore()** method correctly. I will post the result later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for M. Deinum, NewUser and Wim Deblauwe. With their help, I finally figured out the problem. The previous JUnit4 class is not correct.

The proper solution to solve this problem is to cast **Performance** into **Encoreable**, and then call the performEncore() method.

The code is as follow:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes= ConcertConfig.class)
public class OnePerformanceTest {
    @Autowired
    private Performance performance;

    @Test
    public void perform() throws Exception {
        Encoreable encoreable = (Encoreable)(performance);
        encoreable.performEncore();
    }
}
```

[image: screen capture of the final result]